# How to add buttons next to each list item to delete the item when clicked on its corresponding delete button

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have no idea of delete the list items that corresponds to the each list. Even Though i came with remove child method still bit confusing and got error and stuck to the same point.

suggest me how to code this better and efficient way!!!
and also i attached my code after adding strike

> kindly help me

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

function inputLength() {
 return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
 var li = document.createElement("li");
 li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
 ul.appendChild(li);
 input.value = "";
}

function addListAfterClick() {
 if (inputLength() > 0) {
  createListElement();
 }
}

function addListAfterKeypress(event) {
 if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
  createListElement();
 }
}

for(var i=0; i<li.length; i++)
{
 li[i].addEventListener("click", function(event)
 {
  event.target.classList.toggle("done");
 });
}


button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);

input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Javascript + DOM</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Shopping List</h1>
 <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
 <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
 <button id="enter">Enter</button>
 <ul>
  <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook</li>
  <li>Jello</li>
  <li>Spinach</li>
  <li>Rice</li>
  <li>Birthday Cake</li>
  <li>Candles</li>

  <!-- <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook</li><button id="delete">delete</button>
  <li>Jello</li><button id="delete">delete</button>
  <li>Spinach</li><button id="delete">delete</button>
  <li>Rice</li><button id="delete">delete</button>
  <li>Birthday Cake</li><button id="delete">delete</button>
  <li>Candles</li><button id="delete">delete</button> -->


 </ul>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to cross out the new items? Or just delete them?

Comment: i want to delete the list  with a delete button

Comment: Do you want to delete all the list?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `<button>` inside the `<li>` element and put a `click` event on it something like this:

```
if( event.target.classList.contains('done') ) {
    // add delete button
    const buttonElem = document.createElement('button');
    buttonElem.innerText = 'delete';
    buttonElem.onclick = function() { // remove list item here
        this.parentElement.remove()
    };
    event.target.appendChild(buttonElem);
} else {
    // remove the delete button
    event.target.getElementByTagName('button').remove();
}
```

This should be inside the `click` event listener after the `done` toggle. Basically if the list item classList contains the `done` class, then add a button with an already predefined event handler inside the `li` elem. Inside the `onclick` the `this` contains the actual element (`button`) the click happened. This is why we go up the DOM tree one level with the `parentElement` and call a `remove()` function the whole `li` elem is removed from the DOM.
If the `done` class is not present it means that the task is "undone" and the button itself needs to be removed.

On the other hand I'd rather use a list in an Array and use a "render" function. This way there would be a "single-source-of-truth". As I always say... put logic in the JS and let the HTML only react to this.

Answer (score 1):

Create function for adding "Delete" button.

```
function addDelButton(parent) {
var buttonElem = parent.appendChild(document.createElement("button"));
buttonElem.innerHTML = "Delete";
buttonElem.onclick = function() {
    this.parentElement.remove();
}}
```

Insert that function into createListElement function like that:

```
function createListElement() {
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
addDelButton(li);
ul.appendChild(li);
input.value = "";}
```

To Add button with functionality to already existing list items :

```
for(var i=0; i<li.length; i++)
{
    li[i].addEventListener("click", function(event)
    {
        event.target.classList.toggle("done");
    });
    addDelButton(li[i]);
}
```